# Please explain this Ruby method that returns number of repeat letters

Tags: ruby

Can anybody please explain this code? I don't understand specifically:

```
  elsif idx2 > idx1
    is_repeat = true
  end
```

1. Why are we comparing indices to determine if a letter has been
   repeated?
2. Also what does the 'next' term do inside of the if statement?

The full code is shown below:

```
# Write a method that takes in a string and returns the number of
# letters that appear more than once in the string. You may assume
# the string contains only lowercase letters. Count the number of
# letters that repeat, not the number of times they repeat in the
# string.
#
# Difficulty: hard.

def num_repeats(array)
  repeats = 0

  idx1 = 0
  while idx1 < array.length
    is_repeat = false
    idx2 = 0
    while idx2 < array.length
      if array[idx1] != array[idx2]
        idx2 += 1
        next
      elsif idx2 < idx1
        # will have previously counted this repeat
        break
      elsif idx2 > idx1
        is_repeat = true
      end

      idx2 += 1
    end

    if is_repeat
      repeats += 1
    end

    idx1 += 1
  end

  return repeats
end
```

Comment: Voting to close for two reasons: First, good answers would be too long for this format (Q&A).  Second, there are two questions in one.  (The second being "what does the 'next' [do?]".)  Please split your question into two, more specific questions.

Comment: It looks like you pasted your homework in here :( Question should be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both conditions before (`if idx2 < array.length` and `elsif idx2 < idx1`) are `false` but `idx2 > idx1` is `true`, than set the local variable `is_repeat` to `true`...